# Brunch javascripts joinTo specific order

Tags: coffeescript, brunch

Coming from Asset Pipeline, where I can define the specific order to load javascript files like so:

```
//= require jquery
//= require some_file
//= require_tree ./some/directory
//= require other_directory/some_file
//= require_tree ./directory
```

How can I express this specific order in brunch's configuration ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#files

Brunch doesn't currently support something like `require_tree`, but you can specify concatenation order as needed, file by file. To avoid listing every file, you can think about only which files need to be ordered at the top and put those in the `before` array, any that need to be at the bottom can go in the `after` array, and brunch will automatically sort the rest.

```
# in config.coffee
files:
  javascripts:
    joinTo:
      'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
      'javascripts/vendor.js': /^vendor/
    order:
      before: [
        'vendor/scripts/console-helper.js',
        'vendor/scripts/jquery-1.7.0.js',
        'vendor/scripts/underscore-1.3.1.js',
        'vendor/scripts/backbone-0.9.0.js'
      ]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I need to load my files from app/ in a very specific order, so I have done it with grunt.

Comment: You still can do so with brunch of course by just listing each file. What are you using in grunt that lets you replicate require_tree?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Brunch will support glob and regex in this way in the future, but it doesn't currently.